# ¿Como buscar con JavaScript en un array sin distinguir mayúsculas/minúsculas?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo una función que me realiza búsquedas correctamente dentro de un array y me devuelve la coincidencia, pero distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.
Necesito que la comparación la haga en ambos extremos en minúsculas para que no distinga.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Este es mi código actual:

```
function buscar(mi_array, valor, pos){
    var results = mi_array.filter(function (mi_array) { return mi_array[pos].startsWith(valor); });
    var firstObj = (results.length > 0) ? results[0] : null;
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Podrías incluír un ejemplo del array en el que buscas? toLowerCase() sirve para pasar a minúsculas, pero debes pasar a minusculas ambos valores. el valor original y el que buscas, cosa que no es posible con la implementación que haces de filter(). Otra posibilidad es usar expresiones regulares

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para estos casos, es muy recomentable y es buena práctica, al momento de hacer la comparación de strings "convertir" [todas a mayusculas](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) o [todas a minusculas](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp).

```
results = mi_array.filter(function (mi_array) { return mi_array[pos].toUpperCase().startsWith(valor.toUpperCase()); })
```